# Weird behavior when using monitor and analogWrite (ESP32)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm currently working on a project where I want to vary the PWM to a motor given an input from a potentiometer. However, I cant seem to use the serial monitor and an analogWrite statement in the same program.

When I run this code I get this output from the serial monitor:

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("WORKING");

  //analogWrite(1, 255);
}

void loop()
{
  
}
```

```
12:09:48.314 -> 
12:09:48.314 -> WORKING
```

However, when I run this code (the only difference is that the `analogWrite()` line is no longer commented out), the serial monitor outputs garbage.

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("WORKING");

  analogWrite(1, 255);
}

void loop()
{
  
}
```

```
{l$ܞ⸮⸮$⸮|⸮⸮l⸮#|⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮#⸮"⸮⸮on⸮lon⸮⸮⸮#p⸮⸮bl`{lp⸮o⸮⸮l⸮⸮bo⸮|⸮⸮⸮#⸮⸮nN⸮$⸮⸮$`⸮on⸮{lor⸮⸮⸮⸮{r⸮ p⸮o⸮s⸮ܜ⸮⸮⸮#o⸮|⸮B⸮⸮on⸮⸮l ⸮No⸮{lor⸮⸮⸮Nrd`{⸮⸮N{d`⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮$`⸮⸮N⸮l
⸮
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Not sure if it helps but im using an ESP8266 NodeMCU purchased from this amazing link: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B081CSJV2V/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081CSJV2V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`analogWrite(1, 255)` is writting to GPIO1. If you look at the pin-out for the ESP8266 NodeMCU, GPIO1 is the TXD line for serial port 0 (it's labeled TXD0). I don't have a NodeMCU schematic handy, but port 0 is typically used for the serial monitor and wired to the USB-UART converter for that purpose. So by writing to GPIO1, you are interfering with the monitor output.

Try doing an `analogWrite` to a different GPIO, for example, GPIO5.

Comment: That was it! A rookie mistake *facepalm*, I totally forgot about pin 0 being special. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Blokz101 yeah many ports on ESP MCUs are mutli-function and one some assemblies they may be dedicated to a particular purpose. Gotta watch for those. I just did a whole board design using an ESP32 module and later, when I later decided I wanted to use Jtag, discovered I used at least one of the ports dedicated to Jtag for some other purpose. I wasn't thinking ahead for Jtag. :-/

Comment: Dang, that's rough but that's also R and D for you XD There's always going to be something you didn't anticipate for lol.